# Lock-free ConcurrentSkipListMap with complex object as value containing a list

Tags: java, concurrency, java.util.concurrent, concurrentskiplistmap

I am developing a program where I have multiple threads accessing a Map stored in the class `Problem`.
This map, for the "value", contains an object (`Slot`) containing a name and a `List` of instances of `Car`.

So, my question is:

Since the first map, accessed by different threads, is thread-safe, will I need a thread safe list for the list inside `Slot` or am I safe with an `ArrayList`? 
Please note that `Car` is an `AtomicReference` and is the critical area where I use `compareAndSet()` on.

```java
        public class Problem {
            ConcurrentSkipListMap<Integer, Slot> slots;
            //...
        }


        public class Slot {
            private String name;
            List<AtomicReference<Car>> cars; // does this need to be a thread safe list?
            //...
        }

        public class Car {
            //...
        }
```

A simple diagram that shows the problem:

[image]

Thank you.

Comment: Well, 2 threads could still access the same slot (the map doesn't and can't prevent that) so they could mess with the list in general, e.g. add, remove or replace elements. Instead of making the list threadsafe you could hide it inside the `Slot` class and provide methods to manipulate the list. Those methods could then synchronize on the slot instance if that fits your needs.

Comment: Thank you, @Thomas, I understand what you say!
Can you help me understand the practical differences between having those synchronized methods in `Slot`, as you suggested, and having the list thread-safe? I mean, they would end up behaving in a similar way, right? Since both would inhibit other threads from executing "the same" request over it.
Thank you very much for your message - it is a nice point.

Comment: "Both would inhibit other threads from executing 'the same' request over it" - no exactly. Synchronization would prevent threads from entering the same scope concurrently but it depends on you how that scope is defined (synchronized methods would make the `Slot` instance the scope). Thread-safe lists (or collections in general) can occur in multiple varieties which define different scopes, e.g. the entire list vs. certain operations only.